# Compute the probability that a given box contains more than one sterile seed

Tags: probability

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

> A farmer estimated that $20\%$ of the pumpkin seeds he produced will not sprout. He sells the seeds in boxes containing $50$ seeds each. Compute the probability that a given box contains more than one sterile seed. Your answer needs to be a number.

I was thinking that if we let $X=$ number of sterile seeds, then we are looking for $P(X>1)=1-P(X \leq 1)$, but after that I do not know what to do.

Comment: Read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: More interesting but not hard. We have $n$ boxes each with $m$ seeds. What is a probability that at least one box contains at least one sterile seed?

Answer (score 1):

Each seed sprouts with probability $0.8$ and is sterile with probability $0.2$. We have $50$ seeds in the box, and I'm assuming their probabilities of sprouting are independent. We get that

$\Pr(\text{no seed in the box is sterile}) = \Pr(X = 0) = (0.8)^{50}$,

$\Pr(\text{exactly one seed in the box is sterile}) = \Pr(X = 1) = (0.2)\cdot(0.8)^{49}\cdot 50$

Because we have $50$ ways of choosing the sterile seed, see [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

So in total : 
$\Pr(X > 1) = 1 - \left((0.8)^{50} + (0.2)\cdot(0.8)^{49}\cdot 50\right)$